# Not able to get the row as html?

Tags: java, html, swing

I am trying to show particular Row of jtable as html...But instead i am getting the whole table as output ...I just want my row data to be enclosed in html not the whole table....
Below is what i am trying to do ....Where am i making mistake??

```
public static void go() {

    javax.swing.JTable table = new javax.swing.JTable(
            new Object[][] { new Object[] { "Row00", "Row01" }, new Object[] { "Row11", "Row12" }, },
            new Object[] { "Col A", "Col B" });

    table.selectAll();

    javax.swing.TransferHandler handler = table.getTransferHandler();
    if (handler == null) {
        System.err.println("No handler.");
        return;
    }
    int actions = handler.getSourceActions(table);
    if ((actions & javax.swing.TransferHandler.COPY) == 0) {
        System.err.println("Not copy.");
        return;
    }

    java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard clipboard = new java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard(
            "Export");
    try {
        handler.exportToClipboard(table, clipboard, javax.swing.TransferHandler.COPY);
    } catch (IllegalStateException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable transferable = clipboard.getContents(null);
    if (transferable == null) {
        System.err.println("clipboard");
        return;
    }

    if (!transferable.isDataFlavorSupported(HTML_STRING_FLAVOR)) {
        System.err.println("not supported");
        return;
    }
    try {
        Object data = transferable.getTransferData(HTML_STRING_FLAVOR);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
```

Comment: `Where am i making mistake??` - Where is your [mcve]??? How many times do you need to be told a proper `MCVE` should be posted with every question??? Until a problem is solved you don't know where the problem is, so we need to be able to compile the code and test it, when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `table.selectAll()`, just use the `setRowSelectionInterval(int indexBegin, int indexEnd)` method of `JTable` .

Example for the first row only :

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
```

Comment: thanks . But i was wondering how to get the column header also in same format

Comment: You also have a `setColumnSelectionInterval` method that you may find helpful .

Comment: Thank you very much